# NestJS: use Typeorm (0.3.x) custom repository inside transactions

Tags: orm, nestjs, repository, typeorm

I have an old code base in `NestJS` that depends heavily on **Typeform's custom repositories** and now I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version (nest and typeorm). However, I'm unable to `transactionalEntityManager.getRepository(AnyCustomRepository)` directly inside the transaction.

I have tested almost all solutions on the website and others and all of them failed to get `AnyCustomRepository` inside the transaction.

The nearest solution I ended up with is from this [artical](https://tech.durgadas.in/creating-and-using-custom-repositories-in-nestjs-with-typeorm-0-3-c7ac9548ad99)

**user.repository.ts**

```js
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

export interface UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  this: Repository<User>;
  getUsers(): Promise<User[]>;
  getUser(id: number): Promise<User>;
  createUser(user: { firstName: string; lastName: string; isActive: boolean });
}

export const customUserRepository: Pick<UserRepository, any> = {
  getUser(this: Repository<User>, id) {
    return this.findOne({ where: { id } });
  },

  getUsers(this: Repository<User>) {
    return this.find();
  },

  createUser(this: Repository<User>, user) {
    return this.save(user);
  },
};
```

**users.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  getDataSourceToken,
  getRepositoryToken,
  TypeOrmModule,
} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { customUserRepository } from './user.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
      inject: [getDataSourceToken()],
      useFactory(datasource: DataSource) {
        return datasource.getRepository(User).extend(customUserRepository);
      },
    },
    UserService,
  ],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Inside `UsersService` class, this is what only worked so far (**Not a good approach**):

```js
  async testTransaction() {
    this.dataSource.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
      const userCustomRepository = transactionalEntityManager
        .getRepository(User)
        .extend(customUserRepository); // only way to use custom repository so far
   
      await userCustomRepository.getUsers().then(console.log);
    });
```

Is there another (**more direct and cleaner**) way that doesn't require to use `.extend()` in every transaction?